# what is the geometric meaning of total variation for function with two variables?

Tags: real-analysis

what is the geometric meaning of total variation for function with several variables? I also define a function space like this:$V_\Omega=\{f:\Omega\rightarrow R|\|f\|<\infty\}$, where
$\|f\|=\sup_{l\ \text{is a line in}\  \Omega}\sup_{\{P_i\}\subset l}|f(P_{i+1})-f(P_i)|$. Is it same as the space of bounded variation?

Comment: It's old, but [*On definitions of bounded variation for functions of two variables*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1933-035-04/S0002-9947-1933-1501718-2/) by Clarkson/Adams [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (1933), 824-854] might be of use as a survey of early work. Also, you might find more recent work by looking for papers that cite this one. (I don't know enough about this topic to directly address your question.)

Answer (score 2):

The modern definition (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_several_variables)) is that a function $f$ is of bounded variation if it satisfies $\int |\nabla f| < \infty$, where $\nabla f$ is the weak (distributional) gradient. The weak formulation makes sense for $L^1$ functions $f$.

With this definition the function $f(x,y) = \ln (x^2+y^2)$ is of bounded variation in the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (since $|\nabla f(x,y)| = 2(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$ is integrable on the disk), but the variation on any line passing through $0$ is infinite, so your definition is not equivalent.